# Prove the second derivative of a function has a zero in an interval given constraints

Tags: forall, exists

I'm wondering how to express [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4610517/question-on-proving-the-second-derivative-is-0) in a form computable by *Mathematica*:

- Assume $f(x), f^\prime (x),$ and $f^{\prime \prime} (x)$ exist and are continuous for all $x$.
- $|f(x) - \sin x| \leq 1/3$ for all $x$.

Show that $f^{\prime \prime} (x)$ has at least one zero in the open interval $(0, 2 \pi)$.

My (incorrect) attempt is:

```
\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[ForAll]\), \(x\)]\(\((Abs[
    f[x]\  - \ Sin[x]\  <= \ 1/3])\)\ \(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Exists]\), \(x\  \[Element] \((0, 2\ \[Pi])\)\)]D[
     f[x], {x, 2}] == 0\)\)\)
```

---

Extended response to 64494's comment, below:

The above *is* *Mathematica*.  Consider

- "[Automated vector space proofs using Mathematica](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/3572865.3572866)," Aaron E. Naiman, *ACM Communications in Computer Algebra* **56**(1):1--13, issue 219, March 2022

Clearly (by its title and peer-reviewed publication) dealing with *Mathematica*.  In that paper the author uses *Mathematica* to prove (or disprove) theorems about vector spaces.

A sample:

Reduce[!(
*SubscriptBox[([ForAll]), (s)](
*SubscriptBox[([Exists]), (t)]\ s\ t\  < \ 0)), Reals]

The *Mathematica* statement can be read:  "For all $s$, there exists a $t$ such that $s$ times $t$ is negative."

(This statement is of course FALSE, given the case $s=0$, and *Mathematica* computes precisely that answer.)

This is precisely the kind of automated reasoning I'd like to apply to the problem posed above.

Here's another example:

```
Resolve[ForAll[x, a x^2 + b x + c > 0]]
```

as listed [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ForAll.html).

*Mathematica* is rather powerful for automated reasoning about equations and relations, but I had difficulty applying it to the problem stated above.  I have a feeling *somebody* can solve it.

Clear?

Comment: David, I think that these links might be of interest to you since they are the demonstrations of the [mean value theorem](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/MeanValueTheorem/) and [intermediate value theorem](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/IntermediateValueTheorem/). Not sure if you knew about these or not. Also, a clarifying question: are you trying to build a routine from scratch that does the trick or do you want to use built-in functions?

Comment: I'm interested in using existential quantifiers (ForAll, Exists, ...) and such to "prove" this relation in *Mathematica*.  In another context:  Reduce[\!\(\*
SubscriptBox["\[ForAll]", 
RowBox[{"s", ",", 
RowBox[{"s", "\[Element]", 
TemplateBox[{},
"Reals"]}]}]]\(\*
SubscriptBox["\[Exists]", 
RowBox[{"t", ",", 
RowBox[{"t", "\[Element]", 
TemplateBox[{},
"Reals"]}]}]]\ s\ t\  < \ 0\)\)]

Comment: This is math, not Mathematica. At the present and in the near future `ForAll` and `Exists` do not deal with functions as variables.

Comment: Quantification over functions is second-order logic. Mathematica's theorem prover works only for a subset of first-order logic. However, it may be possible to answer this if you restrict your $f$ to a certain class of functions parametrized by a finite set of parameters, e.g a truncated Taylor series.

Comment: @flinty: I have strong doubts about trig polynomials instead of polynomials .

Answer (score 5):

The following shows a +/- band of 1/3 around Sin[x]

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Sin[x] + 1/3, Sin[x] - 1/3}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]

In the interval {1,2] f must somewhere have a negative second derivative. Similar, it must have a positive second derivative somewhere in [4,5]. As the second derivative is continuous, it must have a zero somewheer in between.

Comment: Sorry, "In the interval {1,2] f must somewhere have a negative second derivative" is built on the sand.

Comment: @user64494 If one has nothing to say, one should do so.

Comment: I think the intervals should be `(0, π)` and `(π, 2π)` in your argumentation.

Comment: " If one has nothing to say, one should do so": exactly.

Comment: DanielHuber:  I'm quite familiar with *illustrating* such results, but my question focusses on automated *reasoning* about such results.  See my appended comment.

Answer (score 2):

I appreciate the purpose of this question. Is to automate proof. @DanielHuber answer is almost a visual proof or at least motivates proof.

I have upvoted @DanielHuber

[image]

I apologize for the tardy nature of the post and of course for errors.

The inequalities, repeated use of mean value theorem and final intermediate value theorem could, perhaps,be mimicked in Mathematica but I am uncertain how to “automate reasoning”.

Comment: Thanks ubpdqn:  I will try to translate the handwritten notes into *Mathematica* code and if I succeed will post the code in the original problem.

Comment: There is an error on third line. Inequality should read: -2/3<f(pi/2)-f(0)-1<2/3. Apologies for any other errors. It does not change the rest.